# LLMや深層学習実装時に利用する Azure VM のスペックをどう見積もればよいか

Tags: azure, 深層学習

LLM(Large Language Model)や深層学習を利用可能な環境をAzure VM上で構築したいのですが、一般的にどれくらいのスペックが必要でしょうか。以下の候補からご回答いただけますと幸いです。

※もちろんしたいことやコストによって最適なインスタンスが決まると思うのですが、検討するための情報としてどのインスタンスでVMを構築することが多いのか知りたいです。
[image: Azure VMスペック]

Comment: 具体的な情報が無いと、残念ながら (当サイトでは避けるべき) アンケートのような質問になってしまうと思います。

Answer (score -1):

計算量を処理しきれるスペックの中から安いものを選ぶとよいと思います。
※具体的な答えになっておらず、申し訳ございません。